# how to embed an image with html using MultiEmailAlternatives?

Tags: django

Here I am trying to send image alongside with html template.For this i follow two approach
1> first approach i made logo_data() function to fetch image and I attached with `msg.attach(logo_data())` after `msg.attach_alternative()` but this method didn't worked.
2>In second approach I send the current_site to the template through context with `get_current_site()` method and define image with static tag like this in the template but i didn't worked out as well.

How can I send email with images also.Sending html template is working fine only the images on the template are not displaying

```
<img src="{{site}}{% static 'dist/img/logo.png' %}"
```

views.py

```
def logo_data():
    with open(finders.find('static/dist/img/logo.png'), 'rb') as f:
        logo_data = f.read()
    logo = MIMEImage(logo_data)
    logo.add_header('Content-ID', '<logo>')
    return logo

def send_mail(request):
.............
            site=get_current_site(request)
            html_content = render_to_string('mailverification/guest_notification_after_cleaning.html',{'site':site.domain})
            subject, from_email, to = 'Hello', settings.EMAIL_HOST_USER, email
            msg = EmailMultiAlternatives(subject, text_content, from_email, [to])
            msg.attach_alternative(html_content, "text/html")
            msg.attach(logo_data())
            msg.send() 
            return HttpResponse('mail send')
```

Comment: In your template that you're rendering as string, you can use `{% load static %}`, that way you can directly load the images if they are in your static path.

Comment: i already did it but not working

Comment: can you try adding some public images instead of adding image from local system?

Comment: post the most relevant version of your template please.